# Launch of orange3

Tags: python

I tried to launch of Orange 3 on Anaconda. But launch have produced errors below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\tomo\Anaconda2\envs\orange3\Scripts\orange-canvas-script.py", line 6, in 
from Orange.canvas.__main__ import main
File "C:\Users\tomo\Anaconda2\envs\orange3\lib\site-packages\Orange\canvas\__main__.py", line 30, in 
from Orange.canvas.application.canvasmain import CanvasMainWindow
File "C:\Users\tomo\Anaconda2\envs\orange3\lib\site-packages\Orange\canvas\application\canvasmain.py", line 61, in 
from .canvastooldock import CanvasToolDock, QuickCategoryToolbar, \
File "C:\Users\tomo\Anaconda2\envs\orange3\lib\site-packages\Orange\canvas\application\canvastooldock.py", line 25, in 
from ..document.quickmenu import MenuPage
File "C:\Users\tomo\Anaconda2\envs\orange3\lib\site-packages\Orange\canvas\document\__init__.py", line 17, in 
from .schemeedit import SchemeEditWidget
File "C:\Users\tomo\Anaconda2\envs\orange3\lib\site-packages\Orange\canvas\document\schemeedit.py", line 37, in 
from .suggestions import Suggestions
File "C:\Users\tomo\Anaconda2\envs\orange3\lib\site-packages\Orange\canvas\document\suggestions.py", line 7, in 
from .interactions import NewLinkAction
File "C:\Users\tomo\Anaconda2\envs\orange3\lib\site-packages\Orange\canvas\document\interactions.py", line 28, in 
from ..canvas import items
File "C:\Users\tomo\Anaconda2\envs\orange3\lib\site-packages\Orange\canvas\canvas\items\__init__.py", line 9, in 
from .annotationitem import TextAnnotation, ArrowAnnotation
File "C:\Users\tomo\Anaconda2\envs\orange3\lib\site-packages\Orange\canvas\canvas\items\annotationitem.py", line 7, in 
import CommonMark
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommonMark'
```

Acutually I found these error on this web and tried to install the r-commonmark 1.4 but it does not work well now.

Please tell me how to deal with it.

Comment: Please clarify "and tried to install the r-commonmark 1.4 but it does not work well now". Why are you trying to install an R package instead of the python version to provide the missing python module? What went wrong and is not "working well"

Answer (score 0):

CommonMark is a package that Orange used. It was renamed in the latest release what causes that imports do not work. The issue should be solved by installing newer Orange3 version3.16.0